# Issue in creating platform using phonegap CLI

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have used phonegap before to create android platform and successfully run it on my device using emulator.

Now I have issue once I create android version and try to import it to Android studio, it gives me this error:
Error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

I have tried many solution exist in the website and youtube, and I already downloaded all build tools and API.

I am afraid that the problem is in phonegap instead, so I notice the output command after typing: phonegap platform add android is the following:

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzdQ5.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Ou2.png)

Comment: I dont see any error trace in your output

Comment: the error: Error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher. is in android studio after I import phonegap platform. the figure of 2 output is once I type the command of creating android I got them, like very long command (it was not like this before )

Comment: did you tried installing required android build tools using SDK manager?

Comment: yes I did, and I did install other versions like 22, 23, 24. its not working !

Comment: Could you post the updated error trace or you are getting the same error still?

Comment: I am getting same error

Comment: Have you set the right android home path in system variables?